# How to sync user database with "user role editor" plugin enabled

Tags: user-roles

I already know how to sync user database for multiple wp installations from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/multiple-wp-install-with-same-users-database). I don't know how to sync user database with custom user roles.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to sync user roles between multiple WordPress installations?

Comment: @m0r7if3r yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User roles and associated capabilities are all stored in the `$prefix_options` table in the `$prefix_user_roles` (note that in both of these `$prefix` is a variable, so if your `$prefix` is `foo_`, your table will be `foo_options`).  You need to sync this value between databases.  As far as I'm aware, there is not a way to sync just this one option beyond connecting to the needed table for it.  You will likely need custom SQL for this.

User capabilities should already be synced, as these are stored in the `$prefix_user_meta` table, and syncing that table was covered in the answer that you linked to in your question.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no need for any extra effort to sync user roles?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between roles and capabilities?

Comment: No, I don't :( Will research

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities Capabilities are what a user can do.  Capabilities can be assigned individually or can be assigned to a role, which is then assigned to a user (eg: Administrator, Editor, etc).  My answer is how to carry over the roles and their associated capabilities, capabilities assigned to individual users are stored in the `$prefix_user_meta` table, so those should already have carried over.