# Use members from 1 site on another one

Tags: users, login, table

I have two different wordpress installations and want to use the same users, I have Site_A with all the users logins with buddypress and bbpress, Site_B will be capable of letting the users from Site_A to post on the new site. Site_A is the "root" domain and Site_B a subdomain.

I'm not sure if the solution is using MultiSite option, I already change the prefix on Site_B and connect the Database with this thread: [Multiple WP install with same users database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/multiple-wp-install-with-same-users-database)

Site_B is accesign the table and I can login, the problem is when I try to go the dashboard is telling me that I don't have permission to do that and even if I try to modify mi profile is only let me make the changes on the Buddypress.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.

P.S. I have 1 separate subdomain working with a standalone wordpress installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users created in Site_A have **roles** assigned to them. Same users are available in Site_B but they have **no roles** assigned. Create a PHP script sync-admins.php with the following code in it:

```
<?php
// load WordPress environment
require( 'wp-load.php' );

// REPLACE 'siteb_' with table prefix of Site_B in line below!
$tblPrefixOfSite_B = 'siteb_';

// administrator's capability
$capability = array( 'administrator' => TRUE );

if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $tblPrefixOfSite_B . 'capabilities', $capability );
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $tblPrefixOfSite_B . 'user_level', 10 );
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    echo 'You must be logged in as an administrator';
}
?>
```

Place this script in root of Site_A. Login as an administrator to Site_A. Now execute the script. This will properly assign a role of 'administrator' to the administrator of Site_B. Now you can login to Site_B as an administrator and add roles to other users.

Comment: Thank your very much!!! this is the solution Frank, now i can see the dashboard and everything, only one last question, I have to do this for each role or with this script is all ready do that? Thanks again I was looking like crazy for the solution

Comment: That was a quick solution to get you started. If you want roles match for all users the script has to be modified. Is this your scenario?

Comment: Actually no, I already check with the other roles and everything is working great, thanks again for the help, I really appreciated. Have a great day